# Setting prototype and performance issues

Tags: javascript, es6-class

There is a big red warning label on the Mozilla page for [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) and I've been trying to understand what exactly the optimization issues with changing the prototype are, but I don't think I have, so I'll come right out and ask: Will the code below cause performance problems or is it safe?

```
class A {}

function B () {
    if ( !new.target ) {
        return new B();
    }
}

B.prototype = A.prototype;
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

A little background: Function B is supposed to be the only part of the library that will be exposed. Ideally it should be possible to use B without `new` but also use `instanceof B` to identify objects.

Comment: Changing the prototype of an existing instance is "the slow operation".

Comment: Oh! So I completely misunderstood that then?

Comment: @PeterCoester Yes. Nowhere in your code are you using `Object.setPrototypeOf` :-)

Comment: Thanks Teemu! Thanks Bergi! And sorry for posting a duplicate!